# How to set background color of a specific UITabelViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, date

I have a dynamic tableview. 
It present specific information for a whole month. 
Every day has its own cell.
And the objective is set background color of the cell which has same date as today.

First. I'm setting every cell's tag inside `cellForRow indexPath`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MonthlyCell", for: indexPath)

        guard let monthlyCell = cell as? MonthlyTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Designated cell couldn't found")
        }

        monthlyCell.tag = indexPath.row
        return monthlyCell
    }
```

I have also an extension. Which gives me today's day as an `Int`:

```
extension Date {
    static var nowDayAsInt: Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let component = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: Date())
        return component.day!
    }
}
```

And lastly I'm updating custom cell's background in its own class:

```
class MonthlyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    if Date.nowDayAsInt == (self.tag + 1) {
            self.setDiagonalGradientBackground()
            self.makeRoundedCorners()
        }
}
```

`self.setDiagonalGradientBackground()` & `self.makeRoundedCorners()` are also from `UIView` extension, which I think names are self explanatory.

**Result:** It always sets two or more cells background color:

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgZw.jpg

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that screenshot after a scroll and the cell was reused? Add an `else{self.setDefaultBackground()}`

Comment: Yes. Whenever you scroll down or change screen and come back it duplicates

Comment: Then just add the `else` statement to set the default background color. After your 'if Date.nowDayAsInt...` where you're setting the gradient background.

Comment: Thanks @Don That solved the issue

Comment: You can reset it in prepareForReuse,This is beacuse the cell is not change to default when iwas reut sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused, if you change the UI on a particular condition you have to add an `else` clause to set a default value

```
class MonthlyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    if Date.nowDayAsInt == self.tag {
        self.setDiagonalGradientBackground()
        self.makeRoundedCorners()
    } else {
        // set default appearance
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vadian. I couldn't think that else is the issue. That solved it